# Função para adicionar nova coluna no R

Tags: r, if, data.frame, dplyr, else

Como eu posso adicionar uma nova coluna ao meu data.frame com a soma dos valores dividido por 2 de duas colunas da tabela? Exemplo:

```r
x <- (2, 5, 6)

y <- (8, 5, 3)

z <- Nova coluna: soma de (A + B)/2.
```

Eu tenho usado o `ifelse` e pacote `dplyr` mas não funcionou. Obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

### Dados

Notei que o comando `c` estava faltando, o que permite a formação do vetor.

```
x <- c(2, 5, 6)

y <- c(8, 5, NA)
```

### R Base

```
Criando um vetor z

z <- (x+y)/2
z
[1] 5,0 5,0 NA
```

### Dplyr

Para trabalhar com este pacote é necessário criar um `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tibble(
    x = x,
    y = y
  )
```

#### Operação simples

```
df %>% 
  mutate(z = (x+y)/2)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     8   5  
2     5     5   5  
3     6     NA   NA
```

#### Operação por linha (rowwise)

Com o `rowwise` você consegue aplicar os comandos abaixo linha a linha, assim seria possível usar um comando como `sum`, tendo o parâmetro `na.rm = TRUE`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(z = sum(c(x,y),na.rm = TRUE)/2)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     8     5
2     5     5     5
3     6    NA     3
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou. Se me permite fazer outra pergunta...eu tenho dados NAs na coluna Y e queria saber como repetir os valores da variável x na nova coluna quando o Y for NA.

Comment: @JeanneFranco é possível, utilizando funções que permitem esta consideração do NA em seus cálculos. Atualizei minha resposta adicionando um `NA` no vetor Y